# DeepFix - Location Biased Convolution

Tags: filter, pytorch, convolution, conv-neural-network

I got a question regarding this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.02927.pdf

In the Network Architecture they implement something called **location biased convolution**.

Basically it is 16 2d-gausians appended to the 512 filters of the convolutional layer (See figure 5 from the paper)
[Picture of Location Biased Convolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqd4p.png).

I want to implement this in PyTorch, but have no clue how to add fixed filters to a convolutional block. The weights should be trained as discussed in the paper.

Can anyone give a hint of what to do or has done this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what it looks like in the figure you provided, they append the location priors to the data, i.e.

```
location_priors = generate_gaussians(positions, variances, data.size())
data_w_loc_priors = T.cat((data, location_priors), dim=1)
```

Now, the number of in_channels for your convolution just needs to be adjusted accordingly: If you had 512 in_channels before, you now have 512 + number of location priors.